# soap client error bad request

Tags: php, xml, laravel, soap

I need to use a webservice with php and I got the bad request error,

this is my code:

```
try{

    $client = new \SoapClient("http://54.88.59.192/Cashier/SwCashier.asmx?wsdl");
    $params = new \SoapVar('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XMLTransaccion><DatosTransaccion><idTransaccion>06b09c6b-f9e3-4371-a3ef-4af947d2e488</idTransaccion><idServicio>0001</idServicio><tipoTransaccion>00</tipoTransaccion><fechaTransaccion>20160527015625</fechaTransaccion><usuarioRed>pagofacil</usuarioRed><passwordRed>123456PF</passwordRed><usuarioCaja>jperez</usuarioCaja><idCaja>0016</idCaja><idRed>6548</idRed></DatosTransaccion><DatosServicio><idCliente>pepe@gmail.com</idCliente><username>pepe</username><name>pepen</name><lastname>pepe@gmail.com</lastname></DatosServicio></XMLTransaccion>', XSD_ANYXML);

    $res = $client->GetServiceTransaction($params);
    $res->GetServiceTransactionResponse();
    var_dump($res);

}catch(\soapFault $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```

And the Data should be sent by xml this is the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLTransaccion>
    <DatosTransaccion>
        <idTransaccion>06b09c6b-f9e3-4371-a3ef-4af947d2e488</idTransaccion>
        <idServicio>0001</idServicio>
        <tipoTransaccion>00</tipoTransaccion>
        <fechaTransaccion>20160527015625</fechaTransaccion>
        <usuarioRed>pagofacil</usuarioRed>
        <passwordRed>123456PF</passwordRed>
        <usuarioCaja>jperez</usuarioCaja>
        <idCaja>0016</idCaja>
        <idRed>6548</idRed>
    </DatosTransaccion>
    <DatosServicio>
        <idCliente>pepe@gmail.com</idCliente> 
        <username>pepe</username> 
        <name>pepen</name> 
        <lastname>pepe@gmail.com</lastname>         
    </DatosServicio>
</XMLTransaccion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check validity of your request:

$client = new \SoapClient("http://54.88.59.192/Cashier/SwCashier.asmx?wsdl", **array('trace' => 1)**);

$params = new \SoapVar('GetServiceTransaction($params);

**echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";**

Comment: dont work, i got this error SoapVar::SoapVar(): Invalid type ID

Comment: Hi, am also getting the same error, have you solved it?, if yes please share the information how you solved.